# My cart items aren't printing in the same order in which they're placed

Tags: php, arrays, session, foreach, e-commerce

My code isn't printing the products in the order I placed them into the cart session. The product ids are as follow:
Apples value of 2
Blackberries value of 3
Green grapes value of 6
As you can see in the printed array, the order in which I placed them into the cart session is Grapes, Blackberries and then Apples but for some reason it's printing in the order of their given values rather than their cart order.

The code still treats each of the products as if they're in the correct place however. For example, Apples are suppose to be the third item in the cart array where the grapes currently are. If the quantity button of the grapes is changed, the quantity of Apples would be changed instead because it's still reading the array correctly.

I suspect the problems lie in one of the loops but I just can't seem to find what it is.

[image]

```
<?php

 $total = 0;
 $id_count = 0;

 if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) and count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0){
     
     $product_ID = array_column($_SESSION['cart'],"product_ID");

     $result = $database->getData();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
        foreach($product_ID as $id){
           if($row['id']==$id){

              print_r($product_ID); 
              print_r($row['product_name:']);
              echo " value: $id";

              $itemQuantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$id_count]['quantity'];
              cartMethod($row['product_name'],$row['product_img'],$row['product_price'], $row['id'], $itemQuantity);
              $total = $total + ($itemQuantity*(float)$row['product_price']);
              $id_count++;
           }
        }
     }
  }
  else{
       echo "<h5>Cart is currently empty</h5>";
  } 
?>
```

This is the getData() function located in a different file.

```
//get method to retrieve database information
     public function getData(){
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename";

          $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

          if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                    return $result;
          }
     }
```

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM $this->tablename"` doesn't have an `ORDER BY` clause. Where should the information about product order be obtained from?

Comment: Information about product order should come from the `$product_ID= array_column($_SESSION['cart'],"product_ID");` the `print_r($product_ID)` showcases what the actual order of the items should be. The `foreach` loop places each item of the `$product_ID` into an `$id` which is then compared against `$row['id']`. The first item in `$product_ID` is Grapes with the id value of 6 but instead of that, the `if()` seems to be comparing the Apples' id first.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the product catalog from the database (`$database->getData()`), and then for each entry in there crosschecking if it exists in `$product_ID`.

So the effective order follows that of the query (which is probably `ORDER BY id` or something i suspect (i can't tell; the code isnt included).

It's not hard to fix but you are building the cart in a very inefficient method here. It would make a lot more sense to do the bulk of data collation (which is what most of this page is), inside the database.

Of course, i don't know what the product catalog looks like in the database, and i don't know what query hides behind `$database->getData()`, so i cannot really give more targetted advice.

---

If i had to guess, i'd suspect that `$database->getData()` contains a query such as `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productid ASC`. If that is indeed the case then i would extend that query so you can feed the `$_SESSION['cart']` data into the `SELECT` query, and join that against the products table.

That way:
A) you have full control over the ordering
B) you only have to return the relevant products and not "all" products, muchhh more efficient.
C) you dont have to mix&match the 2 datasets in PHP

Comment: I added the getData function for clarity. If I wanted to feed the `$_SESSION['cart']` into the `SELECT` query, would I need to replace the asterisk with something like the `$product_ID` variable (which contains the `array_column($_SESSION['cart'],"product_ID")`)?

Comment: No you'd have to introduce it as a `WHERE` or `JOIN` condition. To be fair there are 100 different ways to do it. I suppose the easiest would be to either push the entire `$_SESSION['cart']` variable in , as a json array ; or alternatively a bit sloppier would be to push only the ID numbers in as an array.

Comment: It may also depend on if you're using a modern version of mysql or not.